# Redirigir subdominio en .htaccess y usar URL para redirigir a subdirectorio

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Tengo un sitio, digamos `http://es.misitio.com`, y necesito usar reglas de [.htaccess](/questions/tagged/.htaccess) para redirigir la URL (usando el subdominio para agregarlo como subdirectorio) a `http://www.misitio.com/es`.

Lo mismo para

```
http://en.misitio.com => http://www.misitio.com/en
http://fr.misitio.com => http://www.misitio.com/fr
http://de.misitio.com => http://www.misitio.com/de
```

Esto es lo que tengo:

```
RewriteCond     %{HTTP_HOST}            ^www.misitio.com$       [NC]
RewriteRule     ^(.*)$               http://www.misitio.com/$1  [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Previamente tendrias que tener creado algún directorio donde quieras que se redirija tu regla. (y con los permisos necesarios de lectura)

Puedes hacer lo siguiente, en tu archivo .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^piwik.davidcrx.net [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://davidcrx.net/es/ [R=301,L]
```

Espero que sirva de ayuda ;).

PD: Lo he probado en mi servidor y funciona sin problemas, ya me dices.

Comment: Agregué una mejor explicación en mi pregunta, ya que necesito que funcione para múltiples subdominios. ¡Gracias!